# Data set changed shape after using TfidfVectorizer

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm currently doing Twitter sentiment analysis and i wrote the following classes to prepare the data for my model and then used a transformation pipeline which is the following (If you need the classes i talked about just tell me in comment and then i will add them) :

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('Cleaner', TextCleaner()), 
    ('Tokenizer', TextTokenizer()), 
    ('Lemmatizer', TextLemmatizer()), 
    ('Vectorizer', TfidfVectorizer()

])
```

The TextLemmatizer class is the following:

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
class TextLemmatizer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self):
        self.lemmatizer =  WordNetLemmatizer()

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self 

    def transform(self, X, y=None):

        tweets = X['Tweet']
        tweets = tweets.to_numpy()

        for i, tweet in zip(range(len(tweets)), tweets):
            for sentence in sent_tokenize(tweet):
                for word in word_tokenize(sentence):

                    lemmatized_word = self.lemmatizer.lemmatize(word)
                    tweets[i] = tweets[i].replace(word, lemmatized_word)

        X['Tweet'] = tweets 
        return X
```

when I run the transformation pipeline and i checked the shape of the transformed data(which i called learning_data) :

```
(2, 2)
```

but when i remove the Vectorizer in the pipeline i get the following shape:

```
(5422, 2)
```

Can someone explain the problem and how can i fix it please ?

Comment: What's the format/shape of your input data?  What is the value of `learning_data`, and of the fitted Vectorizer's `get_feature_names`?

Comment: @BenReiniger It's a pandas data frame and its shape is (5422, 2)

Comment: What are the column names?  Could you add the other outputs I requested?  I suspect it's related to having a dataframe as input to the Vectorizer's `fit`.

Comment: @BenReiniger the column names : 'Tweet' and 'Category'